# How can I set the font color in a Kendo chart header?

Tags: css, kendo-asp.net-mvc, telerik-grid

My css file looks like this:

```
#productGrid .k-grid-header .k-header
{
       background-color: blue;
       color: white !important;

}
```

This works for the background-color but not the font color!

My grid code looks like this:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<ProductSummary>()
.Name("productGrid")
.Columns(columns =>
{
    columns.Bound(c => c.Product);
    columns.Bound(c => c.Quantity);
    columns.Bound(c => c.Value).ClientTemplate("£#= kendo.toString(Value, \"n2\") #");
    columns.Bound(c => c.Percentage).Title("%");
})
.HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height: 550px;" })
.Scrollable()
.Sortable()
.DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
    .Ajax()
    .Read(read => read.Action("Products_Read", "Products", new { region = ViewBag.regions[Model.RegionPos].Value }))
)
```

Answer (score 1):

My colleague helped me fix this. It turns out the header is actually a hyperlink.

```
#productGrid .k-link {
    color: #FFFFFF !important;
}
```